# Handling Url Title with Wait in selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm just trying to capture the title of the page using wait in selenium with java.
The code seems to be working correctly for positive test case but for negative, the code in the else{} part does not seem to work. Not sure why I get a TimeOutException before the else part is executed.

Ex. 1. Positive TC: When I enter the value for title as "Log In", it works fine.

Ex. 2. Negative TC: When I enter the value for title as "Log in", the else part is not executed.

```
public class WaitForTitleURL {
    static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://classic.crmpro.com/");
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        By forgotPwd = By.xpath("//a[text()='Forgot Password?']");
        
        
        driver.findElement(forgotPwd).click();
        
        String title = waitForTitleAndCapture("Log in", 5);
        System.out.println(title);
    }
    
    public static String waitForTitleAndCapture(String value, int timeOut) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeOut));
        if(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains(value))) {
            String title = driver.getTitle();
            return title;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Title is not present within the given timeout: " + timeOut);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing the code a bit with Try catch block and it seems to be working fine now.

Can anyone please let me know if this is an acceptable solution or do I need to do something else?

```
public static String waitForTitleAndCapture(String value, int timeOut) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeOut));
    
    try {
        boolean flag = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains(value));
        if(flag) {
            String title = driver.getTitle();
            return title;
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Title is not present within the given timeout: " + timeOut);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: what you mean by acceptable solution ? if your code change solves your problem then it is acceptable solution.

Comment: @newlearner Whether it fits the coding conventions or is there a better way to handle this?